# adding syms expression in some elements of numeric matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, numeric

I have a matrix of numeric data;
(let's say 4*4 )
how can I add a syms expression (e.g 3*s) in some elements of it???
I've tried to add it but I get this Error:

> The following error occurred converting
>   from sym to double:
>   Error using mupadmex
>   Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot
>   convert the input expression into a
>   double array.

Comment: Well you're trying to put a non-numeric element in a numeric array.

Comment: So what should I do to be able to do it maybe if I could define a zero syms matrix it works but I dont know how to define zero syms matrix can anyone help????

Comment: `zeros(m,n,'sym')` (or `sym(zeros(m,n))` in older Matlab versions). That or use a cell array.